# fourier series of 1/(x+1)

Tags: fourier-series

i wanna find the fourier series for  the function f(x)= 1/(x+1) defined from [0,pi]
which  is definied as an even function so Bn=0 now i have to find An but i don't think it is gonna be simple to calculate that integral so i tried to use  differential equation method y+(1+x)y'=0 which is satisfied for f(x) and making 
f(x)= 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} an cos(nx)$$

sinse it a even periodique function , but i couldn't really precede from here  ,can anyone help me what to do next

Comment: Whatever you use, you will end up "calculating that integral". Directly or not.

Comment: but you could use this method for evaluating An and Bn of exp(x) without really calculating them just try it with this equation y'+y=0  y= sum An*cos(nx)+Bn*sin(nx)
y(0)=1  you could find An and Bn without any calculation whatsoever